# How to check a mysql table accessible or not via php

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysql-error-1064

I have self hosted web application and I'm trying to access `information_schema` table some how it can be disabled in some servers. How can check it whether it is accessible or not?

Comment: https://ardamis.com/2008/05/26/a-php-script-for-testing-a-mysql-database-connection/

Comment: Thank you dude it worked

Comment: I am posting the answer below for others. Do mark it correct if it worked for you. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `SHOW DATABASES` and see if `information_schema` is in the list.

But this shouldn't matter right? If you're self hosting you can configure it however you need it.

Comment: Dude `information_schema ` is not related to any database so it wont be shown in `show tables` query and yes i need to get how many user has access for `information_schema `

Comment: How can i configure it ?

Answer (score 2):

Sample Solution To resolve this:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <head>
    <title>MySQL Connection Test</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <style type="text/css">
    #wrapper {
        width: 600px;
        margin: 20px auto 0;
        font: 1.2em Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    }
    input {
        font-size: 1em;
    }
    #submit {
        padding: 4px 8px;
    }
    </style>
    </head>

    <body>

    <div id="wrapper">

    <?php
        $action = htmlspecialchars($_GET['action'], ENT_QUOTES);
    ?>

    <?php if (!$action) { ?>

        <h1>MySQL connection test</h1>

    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>?action=test" id="mail" method="post">

        <table cellpadding="2">
            <tr>
                <td>Hostname</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="hostname" id="hostname" value="" size="30" tabindex="1" /></td>
                <td>(usually "localhost")</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Username</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="" size="30" tabindex="2" /></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Password</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="password" id="password" value="" size="30" tabindex="3" /></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Database</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="database" id="database" value="" size="30" tabindex="4" /></td>
                <td>(optional)</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td><input type="submit" id="submit" value="Test Connection" tabindex="5" /></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    </form>

    <?php } ?>

    <?php if ($action == "test") {

    // The variables have not been adequately sanitized to protect against SQL Injection attacks: http://us3.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string

        $hostname = trim($_POST['hostname']);
        $username = trim($_POST['username']);
        $password = trim($_POST['password']);
        $database = trim($_POST['database']);

        $link = mysql_connect("$hostname", "$username", "$password");
            if (!$link) {
                echo "<p>Could not connect to the server '" . $hostname . "'</p>\n";
                echo mysql_error();
            }else{
                echo "<p>Successfully connected to the server '" . $hostname . "'</p>\n";
    //          printf("MySQL client info: %s\n", mysql_get_client_info());
    //          printf("MySQL host info: %s\n", mysql_get_host_info());
    //          printf("MySQL server version: %s\n", mysql_get_server_info());
    //          printf("MySQL protocol version: %s\n", mysql_get_proto_info());
            }
        if ($link && !$database) {
            echo "<p>No database name was given. Available databases:</p>\n";
            $db_list = mysql_list_dbs($link);
            echo "<pre>\n";
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($db_list)) {
                echo $row['Database'] . "\n";
            }
            echo "</pre>\n";
        }
        if ($database) {
        $dbcheck = mysql_select_db("$database");
            if (!$dbcheck) {
                echo mysql_error();
            }else{
                echo "<p>Successfully connected to the database '" . $database . "'</p>\n";
                // Check tables
                $sql = "SHOW TABLES FROM `$database`";
                $result = mysql_query($sql);
                if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                    echo "<p>Available tables:</p>\n";
                    echo "<pre>\n";
                    while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
                        echo "{$row[0]}\n";
                    }
                    echo "</pre>\n";
                } else {
                    echo "<p>The database '" . $database . "' contains no tables.</p>\n";
                    echo mysql_error();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ?>

    </div><!-- end #wrapper -->
    </body>
    </html>
```

Reference: `[https://ardamis.com/2008/05/26/a-php-script-for-testing-a-mysql-database-connection/][1]`

Comment: I am glad it helped you.

Comment: Thanks buddy , happy coding !

Answer (score 1):

Set database as information_schema  and run query "show tables " from selected database   . If you have read access then you will get all the tables from that db. check result of all queries.